# qualified-id in declaration before '=' token / object counter variable

Tags: c++, class, arduino, header

I'm trying to count how many instances or the class `mole2` there are and store the number in a public static variable called mole_count.

***mole2.h***

```
#ifndef mole2_h
#define mole2_h

#include "Arduino.h"
class mole2 {
  public:
    mole2(int input, int output);
    void popUp();
    void popdown();
    boolean moleBrainThinkPopUpNow();
    void setUpTimer(int up_timer);
    boolean didMoleGetHit();
    void setRecoveryTimer(int recovery_timer);
    void decrementRecoveryTimer();
    boolean dosePlayerMistMole();
    void moleReset();

    int input, output;
    static int mole_count;
    static int odds_of_poping;

  private:
    boolean _is_popped = false;

    int _up_timer = 0;
    int _recovery_timer = 0;

};
#endif
```

***mole2.cpp***

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "mole2.h"

int mole2::odds_of_poping = 10;

mole2::mole2(int input, int output) {
  input = input;
  output = output;
  int mole2::mole_count = mole2::mole_count + 1;
  pinMode(input, INPUT);
  pinMode(output, OUTPUT);
}

void mole2::popUp() {
  _is_popped = true;
  digitalWrite(input, HIGH);
}

void mole2::popdown() {
  _is_popped = false;
  digitalWrite(input, LOW);
}


boolean mole2::moleBrainThinkPopUpNow() {
  if (_recovery_timer == 0 &&  _is_popped == false && rand() % odds_of_poping == 1) {
  popUp();
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}

void mole2::setUpTimer(int up_timer) {
  _up_timer = up_timer;
}

boolean mole2::didMoleGetHit() {
  if (_is_popped == true && digitalRead(input) == HIGH) {
    popdown();
    _up_timer = 0;
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}

void mole2::setRecoveryTimer(int recovery_timer) {
  _recovery_timer = recovery_timer;
}

void mole2::decrementRecoveryTimer() {
  if (_recovery_timer > 0) {
    _recovery_timer--;
  }
}

boolean mole2::dosePlayerMistMole() {
  if (_is_popped == true && _up_timer > 0) {
    _up_timer--;
  }
  if (_is_popped == true && _up_timer == 0) {
    popdown();
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}

void mole2::moleReset() {
  popdown();
  _up_timer = 0;
  _recovery_timer = 0;
}
```

***FullError***

```
Arduino: 1.6.12 (Windows 7), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

C:\Users\Strings\Documents\Arduino\libraries\mole2\mole2.cpp: In constructor 'mole2::mole2(int, int)':

C:\Users\Strings\Documents\Arduino\libraries\mole2\mole2.cpp:9:25: error: qualified-id in declaration before '=' token

   int mole2::mole_count = mole2::mole_count + 1;

                         ^

exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Comment: Where do you define `mole_count`?  I see you defined `odds_of_poping` but I do not see `mole_count`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First this:

```
int mole2::mole_count = mole2::mole_count + 1;
```

has no sense: you're declaring something and assigning it to its value + 1

Anyway, you already declared `mole_count` in your class. Since you're in the constructor, you're in the `mole2` class already (the "qualified-id" bit comes from here), so you just have to do:

```
mole_count++;
```

Also, you have to declare storage for the variable in the .cpp class & initialize it:

```
int mole2::mole_count = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the same thing as with `odds_of_poping`:

Definition:

```
int mole2::mole_count = 0; // initialization can be ommited as static variables are initialized to the default value
```

and later just increment: `++mole_count;`

Answer (score 0):

`int mole2::mole_count` has already been defined. This is trying to make another `int mole2::mole_count`. Lose the `int` and assign to the pre-existing variable.

You also need to allocate storage for and initialize `mole_count`. Place

```
int mole2::mole_count = 0; // replace 0 if starting with more than 0 mole2s
```

in somewhere around

```
int mole2::odds_of_poping = 10;
```

in mole2.cpp

Also watch out for

```
input = input;
output = output;
```

The compiler doesn't know whether you want to use the passed parameter `input` or the class's `input` so it will pick the closest defined `input`, the parameter, on both sides of the = . Refrain from reusing the same variable names in the same places at the same times.

This can be resolved by explicitely stating

```
this->input = input;
this->output = output;
```

Or (my favourite!) by using the [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

```
mole2::mole2(int input, int output): input(input), output(output) {
```

But to prevent other confusion you should still not repeat the names.